# WUI (Web GUI) framework for use with C++

Tags: user-interface, web, embedded

Any recommendations for a WUI framework for use with C++ on Windows and possibly other platforms?

This, [Good C++ GUI library for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows), recommends Qt for multi-platform GUI with C++. I'm looking for something similar that would allow remote web-based GUI access for small light-weight apps.

There's a WUI framework on sourceforge - http://wui.sourceforge.net/wui-overview.php - but it's for Java rather than C++.

Ideal specs:

- Like Qt, works with standard C++
- Like Qt, is multi-platform (Windows, Linux, embedded)
- Access with browser to port, say, 127.0.0.1:8080, or remote access.
- Like a web-appliance (router etc) implements a small webserver for 1 or 2 clients.
- Unlike IIS or Apache, is small and self-contained in the app.
- Optional: Like Qt, has a WYSIWYG designer tool

Why I'd want this:

- For remote access to a GUI on an embedded internet appliance running
  Linux or Windows (xp, Win7 etc)
- To share more code between the embedded application and utilities used for test and diagnostics

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738273/open-source-c-c-embedded-web-server. Also, more info on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) ?